# OpenMP Parallel Element Increment Got Wrong Results When Profile-Guided Optimization is Enabled

Tags: c, openmp, intel, icc

I used Intel OpenMP parallel for directives to increment array elements. However, when Intel Profile-Guided Optimization is enabled, the first and second elements in array will get wrong results.

The code is written in C. It is compiled by Intel Compiler 19.0 toolchain (Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 Update 3) with IDE Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 Education, Intel i7-8750H. The Profile-Guided Optimization is enabled through Project Property Pages -> General -> Intel Specific -> Profile-Guided Build Options. To enable it, I select Phase 1: Instrument for Optimization (`Qprof-gen`).

```
int test[300];
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; idx++) {
        //printf("%d\n", idx);
        test[idx] += 1;
    }
}
```

After executing the parallel for region, the `0`-th to the `99`-th elements in test should be `1`. This is true when profile-guided optimization is disabled. However, when profile-guided optimization is enabled, `test[0]` becomes `12` and `test[1]` remains `0` after execution, while all other 98 elements from the `2`-nd to the `99`-th elements are correctly updated to `1`. Strangely, if I uncomment the `printf` statement, the code will give the correct results even if profile-guided optimization is enabled.

Comment: Putting a `printf` inside the loop is obviously going to defeat most optimizations, that's hardly surprising.  Especially with `test[]` being global, the compiler has to assume that a non-inline function might modify any global variable.  But anyway, this sounds like a compiler bug you should report to Intel, unless there's something OMP specific you forgot to like defining `idx` as an induction variable.  I think you usually only need special stuff about a variable for omp reductions, or at least not for the loop counter.

Comment: I have tested this with my installation and it seems like a bug when the application is running to generate the profile. It seems that after the PGO profile has been applied using `-prof-use`, the code works correctly. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @MichaelKlemm I try with your steps and the program compiled with `-prof-use` seems correct. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for this very interesting, very insightful remark, especially about the compiler optimization mechanism.

Comment: @TonyWu Regardless of this, I will file a bug report with the Intel compiler team. The code should still run correctly with `-prof-gen`.  Otherwise, the profile might contain bogus data or even corrupt the run beyond repair.